# Program to read multiple URLs and generate a word (Should only contains alphanumeric) frequency table

Tags: python

I am writing a Python program to read multiple URLs and generate a word (a word only contains letters A-Za-z0-9) frequency table. Output can be stored in files with names url1.txt, url2.txt

This is what i have so far:

```
import urllib2
import obo

url = 'sample url'

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
text = obo.stripTags(html).lower()
wordlist = obo.stripNonAlphaNum(text)


for s in sorteddict: 
    print str(s)
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: How to proceed further? Followed user3091275 steps, but seeing an import error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use boilerpipe to easily extract the text: https://github.com/misja/python-boilerpipe.

The code might look like this:

```
from boilerpipe.extract import Extractor
from collections import Counter

urls = ['url1', 'url2', ... ] # A list of the urls you want to fetch
# Ask boilerpipe to fetch the data
extractors = [Extractor(extractor='ArticleExtractor', url=url) for url in urls]
# Ask boilerpipe to extract the text
raw_texts = [extractor.getText() for extractor in extractors]
# count the occurrences of words in each text
word_counts = [Counter(text.split(" ")) for text in raw_texts]
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i run this. I see the following error.

    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "test0731.py", line 1, in <module>from boilerpipe.extract import Extractor
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boilerpipe/extract/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import charade
ImportError: No module named charade

I have made sure that charade package is imported

Comment: Did you install boilerpipe using `sudo pip install boilerpipe` ?

Comment: Yes, that was installed correctly and showed success?

Comment: On my side I just had to use pip to install the module, and had no issues with imports. Try reinstalling the package, it should come with charade into it.